# What is the probability that by choosing his answers at random, he will get at least one correct question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Pepe solves an exam with 11 multiple-choice questions, each of which has only one correct answer. There are 2 options for the first question, 3 options for the second question, and so on until he has 12 options for question 11. What is the probability that by choosing his answers at random, he will get at least one correct question?

So, here this problem. I have Knowledge about probability, but this is poor. What I do to solve the problem was to divide the number of favorable cases betwen the number of possible cases, you know, clasica probability.
But I think that the problem is more than that, I think it is not so simple. So, please help me to start the conceptual step, what is the concepto I need to solve it?

Comment: Find the complement: what is the probability he gets every question wrong?

Comment: I am in the same situation, I explain you: My idea is to sum the number of options and the number of right options, then divide them

Comment: And, are you saying that one less the complement is what I am searching?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: But now I have no idea of how to find the complement, what must I divide?

Comment: "*My idea is to sum the number of options and the number of right options, then divide them*"  It isn't clear if you are "summing" things correctly here.  I sure hope you aren't trying to do $1+2+3+4+\dots+11$

Comment: Not, I was trying to sum 2+3+4+...+12, the result, acording to me, is the number of possible cases

Comment: That is wrong too.  Those may be the total possible number of **individual** answers, but it is not the total number of possible ways to give an answer **for each** question.  One of the possible ways he could answer the *entire* test would be having answered 1 for question one, 3 for question two, 1 for question three, 4 for question four, etc...  There are $2\color{red}{\times}3\color{red}{\times}4\color{red}{\times}5\color{red}{\times}\cdots \color{red}{\times}12$ different *answer sheets* possible here.  Multiplication, not addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question of how many ways to get at least one correct answer seems hard, so let us instead answer the opposite question of how many ways there are to get no correct answers.

There is $1$ way to incorrectly answer the first question. 
There are $2$ ways to incorrectly answer the second question. 
There are $3$ way to incorrectly answer the third question. 
$\vdots$
There are $11$ ways to incorrectly answer the eleventh question.

You have found the number of ways to incorrectly answer each question. These incorrect answers can be chosen independently of each other. Therefore, the number of ways to answer the entire test wrong is
$$
1\times 2\times 3\times \dots\times 11
$$

Now that you have found the number of ways to answer all questions wrong, you want to turn this into a probability, so you need to divide by the total number of ways to answer the test. See if you can compute the total number of ways to answer the test by yourself (there are $2$ ways to answer the first question, $3$ to answer the second question, etc).

Finally, when you do this division, you have do remember that we were finding the probability of the complementary event, so we need to do one minus the fraction you get.

Comment: typo: "There are $11$ ways to incorrectly answer the eleventh question"

Comment: I see now my misteke, It was that I  was summing the number of questions when what i had to do was to multiply them, now, the are multply them because of counting principle (I think), so yeah, I think I got it, Thak you, I only must have in mind what was said in the comment above this

Comment: So, my complement would be (1+2+3+4+...+11)/(1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x...x 11), then what I search is one minus the last, Is that right?

Comment: No.  You again went and added in the numerator when that too should be multiplication

Comment: (1 x 2 x 3 x 4 x ... x 11) / (2 x 3 x 4 x 5 x ... x 12)?

Comment: @MarcoMedina Exactly, it should be one minus that fraction you just wrote. Also, there are some common factors in the numerator and denominator you can cancel.

Answer (score 0):

You get the first question wrong with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}$

You get the second question wrong with probability $\dfrac{2}{3}$

You get the third question wrong with probability $\dfrac{3}{4}$

$\vdots$

You get the eleventh question wrong with probability $\dfrac{11}{12}$

---

You get all questions wrong with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{2}{3}\times\dfrac{3}{4}\times\cdots\times\dfrac{11}{12}$ by multiplying all of these together as they are assumed to be independent events which simplifies to $\dfrac{1}{12}$

---

This could alternately be worded by noting there are $1\times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times 11$ ways to choose an incorrect answer to the first **and** choose an incorrect answer to the second **and** choose an incorrect answer to the third problems etc respectively.

This, compared to $2\times 3\times 4\times \cdots \times 12$ ways to choose any answer to the first **and** any answer to the second etc... following from the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  *Since each possible answer sheet to the test is equally likely*, taking the ratio gives the probability of getting no answers correct.

It should be clear that these two answers of $\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{2}{3}\times\cdots\times\dfrac{11}{12}$ and $\dfrac{1\times 2\times \cdots \times11}{2\times 3\times \cdots \times 12}$ are the same.

This probability, again, being the probability of having gotten all wrong.  Getting at least one right is the opposite probability and so is $1-\dfrac{1}{12}=\dfrac{11}{12}$

Comment: I got it, mi final answer is 11/12, Thank you, besides you add a link to the theory, thank you so much